# Find the length of the belt which passes tightly round the wheels of radii $12$ and $5$ inches without crossing.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles, tangent-line

> Two wheels of radii $12$ inches and $5$ inches lie in the same plane and have their centres $25$ inches apart. Find the length of the belt which passes tightly round the wheels without crossing.

Two answers have been posted on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Two-wheels-of-radii-12-inches-and-5-inches-lie-in-the-same-plane-and-have-their-centres-25-inches-apart-What-is-the-length-of-the-belt-which-passes-tightly-round-the-wheels-without-crossing) for this.

Both say (in my words) half of circumference of both the circles plus twice the length of direct common tangent.

Direct common tangent=$\sqrt{d^2-(r_1-r_2)^2}$, where $d$ is the distance between centres.

But both the answers are using the formula $\sqrt{d^2+(r_1-r_2)^2}$

Maybe I am not understanding it properly?

Comment: @VizDracViz https://www.math-only-math.com/important-properties-of-direct-common-tangents.html#:~:text=The%20length%20of%20a%20direct,radii%20of%20the%20given%20circles.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. $\sqrt{d²-(r_1-r_2)²}$ is indeed the correct formula for calculating the length of the direct common tangent. And your way of calculating it is also correct. The person on Quora is wrong, and I know what they might have done wrong to arrive at the incorrect formula for this. Personally, I never recommend Quora for learning OR problem solving. Maths SE is the place to be for problems that might be bothering you.

Comment: It's a curious problem. The numbers seem to have been chosen deliberately to make the length of the common tangent an integer. But the arc lengths seem to require trigonometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In rectangular coordinates $(x, y),$ the circles are $x²+y²=144$ and $(x-25)²+y²=25.$

If $y-mx-c=0$ is a common tangent, then the distance between the center of each circle and the line is the radius of the circle, so that $|c|=12√(1+m²)$ and $|25m+c|=5√(1+m²),$ so

$$5|c|=12|25m+c|.$$

There are two tangents we require, those which intersect (the radii are different) outside the segment joining the centres of the circles. By symmetry, we focus on the one with $c>0,$ so

$$5c=12|25m+c|.$$

Also, we must have that $m<0$ (the larger circle is on the left) and $-c/m>30$ (the $x$-intercept of the tangent required is on the right of the smaller circle).

There are two cases:

$5c=12(25m+c),$ so $-7c=300m,$ or

$5c=-12(25m+c),$ so $17c=-300m.$

Therefore we have that $-7c=300m,$  since it satisfies $-c/m>30.$

Therefore $c²=144(1+m²)$ and $49c²=90000m²,$ so

$90000m²/49=144+144m²,$ or $82944m²=7056,$ so

$m=-7/24,$ and $c=12.5,$ so

$$y=-7x/24+12.5,$$ intersecting the $x$-axis at $(300/7, 0).$

The acute angle of slope is $\arctan(7/24).$

The length of the tangent is given by

$$√((300/7)²-144)-√((300/7-25)²-25)=24.$$

The relevant upper arc of the large circle has central angle $π/2+\arctan(7/24),$ so the arc-length is

$$6π+12\arctan(7/24).$$

The relevant upper arc of the small circle has central angle $π/2-\arctan(7/24),$ so the arc-length is

$$5π/2-5\arctan(7/24).$$

Therefore the total length required is given by

$$2[6π+5π/2+12\arctan(7/24)-5\arctan(7/24)+24]=48+17π+14\arctan(7/24).$$

---

Here is a synthetic approach.

[image]

The green quadrilateral is a parallelogram and it is surmounted by a right triangle. All the action takes place in this triangle.

First, we find the length of the common tangent. The blue length in the triangle is $12-5=7$ and the green length is equal to the distance between the centres of the circles, so is $25.$ Therefore by Pythagoras the required length is given by $√(25²-7²)=24.$

To find the red arcs, we find the angle $\theta,$ whose trigonometric tangent is $24/7,$ so that $\theta=\arctan(24/7).$ But this angle corresponds to the central angle of the smaller red arc, so that the length of this arc is $5\arctan(24/7).$

Also, the central angle of the larger red arc is $π-\arctan(24/7),$ so that the length of the arc is $12π-12\arctan(24/7).$

Therefore the length of the belt required is given by

$$2[24+5\arctan(24/7)+12π-12\arctan(24/7)]=48+24π-14\arctan(24/7).$$

To see that this is the same result as above, use the identity $\arctan(y/x)+\arctan(x/y)=π/2.$

Comment: TLDR. i recommend you shorten this up.

Comment: Thank you. The answer given is $105.38$ inches, which matches with what you got. But I had to use calculator to reach the final value. Any tips to avoid calculator here?

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy how would you shorten it?

Comment: @aarbee $105.38$ is only an approximation to the exact value, which I gave in terms of the arctangent function and the number $\pi$ above, so the number is essentially irrational (you cannot have the exact answer as a fraction of integers).